# Easy Way to change all instances of 'Content Types' in admin to a different phrase

Tags: 7, nodes, users

For a project I am working every Content Type available to a user is a 'Survey'.  The terminology 'Content Type' confuses the users.   I was wondering if there was a simple way to change all menu instances of 'Content Type' to 'Survey' in the admin.  I was thinking use `hook_page_alter` but this could grow teduios and be difficult to maintain.  Has anyone ever done this before? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this with just one or two strings in the user interface ("Content Type" is such a string), you can use the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.

If you end up re-writing lots of phrases, you should make a custom language since String Overrides will cause a performance hit if you use it for too many things.